# Python Pygame: error when using python.draw.rect in an object

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I am fairly new to programming, especially with Object oriented languages. 
I'm trying to draw rectangles as instances of an object, so i can interact with them later. 
I am using pygame.

When using the following line in a for-loop, it will draw the rectangles like expected:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,WHITE,(x_pos,y_pos,box_size, box_size))
```

However when I try to implement this into an Object I get the error that Rect is not a valid argument of pygame.rect. How is this possible? Is it out of the scope of the Object?

Also, is this the correct approach at all?

Your help is much appreciated!

```py
import pygame, sys
import random
from pygame.locals import *

# global variables

display_width = 600
display_height = 400
DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height),0,32)

# Boxes variables
amount_of_boxes = 9
box_size = 30
clear_edge = 1.5 * box_size

# colors
WHITE=(255,255,255)
BLUE=(0,0,255)

# Box Object
class Box:
    hovered = False

    def __init__(self, pos, size):
        self.size = size
        self.pos = pos
        # NOTE TO SELF self.draw.rect(DISPLAY,WHITE,pos,size)

    def draw(self):
        self.set_rend()
        screen.blit(self.rend, self.rect)

    def set_rend(self):
        self.rend = pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,WHITE,self.pos,self.size) # This line gives an error: Rect argument is invalid



def main():
    pygame.init()
    DISPLAY.fill(BLUE)



    boxes = []
    # Drawing random boxes
    for i in range(amount_of_boxes):
        random_x = random.randint(0, 2*amount_of_boxes)
        random_y = random.randint(0, 2*amount_of_boxes)
        x_pos = (random_x/(2*amount_of_boxes))*(display_width -2*clear_edge) + clear_edge
        y_pos = (random_y/(2*amount_of_boxes))*(display_height-2*clear_edge) + clear_edge
        #pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,WHITE,(x_pos,y_pos,box_size, box_size)) 
        boxes.append(Box((x_pos,y_pos),box_size))
        print(boxes)
    for box in boxes:
        box.draw()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd parameter to [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) has to be a tuple with 4 elements (x, y, widht, height):

```py
self.rend = pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,WHITE,(self.pos[0],self.pos[1],self.size,self.size))
```

respectively

```py
self.rend = pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,WHITE,(*self.pos,self.size,self.size))
```

---

If you want to use [`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit)

> ```py
> DISPLAY.blit(self.rend, self.rect)
> ```

then you've to create a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html):

```py
class Box:
    hovered = False

    def __init__(self, pos, size):
        self.size = size
        self.pos = pos
        self.set_rend()

    def draw(self):
        DISPLAY.blit(self.rend, self.rect)

    def set_rend(self):
        self.rend = pygame.Surface((self.size,self.size))
        self.rect = self.rend.get_rect(center = self.pos)
        self.rend.fill(WHITE)
```

But, if you just wat to draw a white rectangle, then you don net need `blit` at all:

```py
class Box:
    hovered = False

    def __init__(self, pos, size):
        self.size = size
        self.pos = pos

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,WHITE,(*self.pos,self.size,self.size))
```

Comment: So essentially rendering a surface and filling it is the same as using pygame.draw.rect?

Comment: @Rumturf `pygame.draw.rect` draws a rectangle onto a surface. But it doesn't create a new Surface. `blit`, puts a Surface onto another Surface. So you've to create one. I've extended the answer.